# get_files() in 2.6 version

Tags: module

I am new to expression engine and following the tutorial on creating a module here:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html

issue is, there is that

> tools_model::get_files()

is no longer valid in EE 2.6. How do I get the files list in the 2.6 version?

Thanks,
Bharath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you lucked out: [Changelog](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#id2)

But it's still in use throughout EE code (for example):

```
ee()->load->library('addons');
$fts = ee()->addons->get_files('fieldtypes');
```

Defined in /system/expressionengine/libaries/Addons.php (line 50 v1.6.1)

...or perhaps the other one in /system/expressionengine/models/file_model.php

```
ee()->load->model('file_model');
$files = ee()->file_model->get_files($dir['id'], $params);
```

But not being in the documentation or formally available to developers can mean that Ellis Labs can change it in the future and therefore render your module broken, so I appreciate you're following the tutorial (which obviously needs updating) I wouldn't use the above function in a commercial environment.

Unless, like the tutorial, they've just not updated the documentation to refer to the function...